# tmux pipe-pane not working

Tags: terminal, screen, tmux

I have a shortcut defined to start logging a pane to a file, and another to stop logging. The shortcuts are active. These are the commands in my `.tmux.conf`:

```
bind-key H pipe-pane "cat >>$HOME/tmux.log"
bind-key h pipe-pane
```

By pressing `C-b ?` I am able to see the definition:

```
   H: pipe-pane "exec cat >>/home/myuser/tmux.log"                                                                                                                                                                                     
   h: pipe-pane
```

The idea is that `C-b H` will start logging and `C-b h` will stop it, for the current pane. It is clear that different panes will collide, but I am not worried about this now. I just want logging to work, and it does not. The shortcuts seem to work fine, and the file is created alright:

-rw-r--r-- 1 myuser mygroup 0 2012-04-28 11:21 tmux.log

But it *always* has size 0. Even after closing. Nothing, never ever, gets written to it. Any ideas on how to debug this issue?

This is the only gripe I have with `tmux` compared to `screen`, where logging has always been a simple task, working out of the box without any configuration needed.

Answer (score 1):

What version of tmux?  Why aren't you using the -o option to pipe-pane?

If this is still producing a zero-length file, try starting tmux with -vvvv, and repeat the pipe-pane commands, and put the logs somewhere.

Comment: No idea which version of tmux: it is not possible to get it from tmux itself (I haven't found the option/command to get it). I am not using `-o` because I have one command to start logging, and another to stop logging. I do not want a toggle command. Anyway, that is not the problem. I have tried with `-o` too and it is doing the same thing. And I have started with `-vvvv` and it is producing lots of debugging output, but no interesting info. Also with less verbose levels (I have tried down to `-v`)

Comment: So you're not prepared to put these logs somewhere, having ruled them out yourself already?  Not useful.

Comment: tmux 1.3 seems to have no way of getting the version, while tmux 1.6 has a `-V` flag for that purpose; I don't have any of the in-between versions around to check. You can try something like `rpm -qi tmux` (depending on your OS and setup) to find out which version of tmux is installed. In any case, try upgrading tmux; that may fix your problem with `pipe-pane`.

Answer (score 0):

For my tmux 1.8, I only got this to work first being inside the tmux window and then hitting

`[Ctrl]+[b]` `[:]`

and then typing:

```
pipe-pane -o 'cat >> ~/output.log'
```

It did not work when I was detached from the tmux session and tried

```
tmux pipe-pane -o -t sessionname:0 'cat >> ~/output.log'
# that does not work for me in tmux 1.8
```